# Converting abbreviation street type names to full names using dictionary for Python script tool?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, cursor, python-script-tool, address

I have a data table with a column 'STREET_TYPE' which are street types (RD, LN, ST, AVE etc.). I want to make a custom tool in ArcMap's toolbox that will expand these abbreviations to their full names using a dictionary. It needs to be able look up the values while ignoring the case sensitivity from the dictionary. In other words, it shouldn't matter if it's upper case or not. I want the end result to be in title case.

Around the same time I want to clean up the data by stripping any whitespaces. Including stripping the empty fields.

How can I do this?

[image: Street_type column sample]

Here is the best I got so far.

```
import arcpy

# set parameters
f1 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
f2 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

# variables
fc = f1
field = f2

    d = { 
    'aly' : 'Alley',
    'ave' : 'Avenue',
    'blv' : 'Boulevard',
    'blvd' : 'Boulevard',
    'cir' : 'Circle',
    'ct' : 'Court',
    'cv' : 'Cove',
    'cyn' : 'Canyon',
    'dr' : 'Drive',
    'expy' : 'Expressway',
    'hwy' : 'Highway',
    'ln' : 'Lane',
    'pkwy' : 'Parkway',
    'pl' : 'Place',
    'pt' : 'Point',
    'rd' : 'Road',
    'sq' : 'Square',
    'st' : 'Street',
    'ter' : 'Terrace',
    'tr' : 'Trail',
    'trl' : 'Trail',
    'wy' : 'Way'
    }

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, field) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] != None: # searches only non-null fields
            row[0] = d[row[0]].title()
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Edit: I changed the dictionary keys to lower cases.
Error I got with this is. 
`\StreetSuffix.py", line 39, in <module> row[0] = d[row[0]].title() KeyError: u'LN'`

With `row[0] = d[row[0].strip().lower()].title()` instead I got this error.
`\StreetSuffix.py", line 39, in <module> row[0] = d[row[0].strip().lower()].title() KeyError: u'lane'`
The first row was changed to "Lane" but nothing else

Edit 2: I changed the last part to.

```
    ...
    'tr' : 'Trail',
    'trl' : 'Trail',
    'wy' : 'Way',
    ' ' : None,
    }

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, field) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        key = row[0].strip().lower()
        if key and key in d:  #  Check key is non-NULL and is in dictionary
            row[0] = d[key]
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

I get this error `\StreetSuffix.py", line 38, in <module>
    for row in cursor:
RuntimeError: The row contains a bad value. [STREET_TYPE]`

When I close the tool and review the table I get this error and the all table data is gone.
[image: error I get]

Edit 3: The length is 5 is why I'm probably getting an error. Copy the data to a new column first then run the tool works.

[image: meta]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1.  Make it Case Insensitive**

Change your dictionary to use all lower-case keys. (eg, `'dr': 'Drive'` ).

Then change your assignment statement to use the lowercase version of the value as the key to your dictionary:

```
row[0] = d[row[0].lower()].title()
```

(I would leave out the `title()` myself, and just make sure that the dictionary values are all correctly title-cased.  But that's up to you.)

Alternative 1:  Create a case insensitive dictionary subclass as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082152/case-insensitive-dictionary (highest voted answer, NOT the accepted answer!).

Alternative 2:  Derive your all-lower-case-keys dictionary dynamically rather than defining the keys that way explicitly:  `lowerKeysDict = {k.lower(): v for (k, v) in d}`

**2.  Handle Whitespace and Empty Strings**

Add the following entry to your dictionary:

```
'': None
```

This will cause your dictionary lookup to replace all empty strings with NULLs.

But if you also want to handle other whitespace, you should strip it out before looking up the dictionary like so:

```
row[0] = d[row[0].strip().lower()].title()
```

Now it will also replace a value of `' '` (space) or tab, etc will NULLs.  It will also clean up any extra whitespace from other values such as `'Dr '` along the way too, causing them to be looked up in the dictionary correctly.

**3.  Handle any other cases that are NOT in the dictionary**

Change your `if` statement to check if the key is in the dictionary.  If not, then ignore it:

```
if row[0] and row[0].strip().lower() in d:
```

**Result**

The last part of the script would then look something like this:

```
    ...
    ...
    'trl' : 'Trail',
    'wy' : 'Way',
    '' : None,
    }

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, field) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        key = row[0].strip().lower()
        if key and key in d:  #  Check key is non-NULL and is in dictionary
            row[0] = d[key]
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```